# stackoverflowerror in tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat, jersey

i am using tomcat 7.0.57 and jersey 1.18.3 version and from time to time get response code 500 from tomcat on requests.
in the catalina.out i see :

```
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [{Servlet_name}] in context with path 
[/{my war name}] threw exception [Servlet execution threw an exception] with 
root cause
java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at java.lang.String.toLowerCase(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.jersey.core.util.StringIgnoreCaseKeyComparator.hash(StringIgnoreCaseKeyComparator.java:53)
    at com.sun.jersey.core.util.StringIgnoreCaseKeyComparator.hash(StringIgnoreCaseKeyComparator.java:48)
    at com.sun.jersey.core.util.KeyComparatorHashMap.keyComparatorHash(KeyComparatorHashMap.java:294)
    at com.sun.jersey.core.util.KeyComparatorHashMap.containsKey(KeyComparatorHashMap.java:359)
    at com.sun.jersey.api.client.filter.HTTPBasicAuthFilter.handle(HTTPBasicAuthFilter.java:78)
    at com.sun.jersey.api.client.filter.HTTPBasicAuthFilter.handle(HTTPBasicAuthFilter.java:81)
```

what can it be ?
i see no cyclic jars in my code , just tomcat ones...(used tattletale to check)
is it tomcat error ?
jersey ?
my own ?
please advise...

Comment: Is that the complete stack trace? If so it looks like you have your stack frame size set ridiculously small!

Comment: no , the at com.sun.jersey.api.client.filter.HTTPBasicAuthFilter.handle(HTTPBasicAuthFilter.java  line seems to go forever ....

Comment: Suggestion: please add a few lines more of your stacktrace. You can take a look to the code using grepcode, [here](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/com.sun.jersey/jersey-bundle/1.18.3/com/sun/jersey/api/client/filter/HTTPBasicAuthFilter.java). With the few lines you've added is a bit difficult to know what happens, but at least it gives you a hint about what could be going wrong. Hope it helps.

Comment: it appeared to be an application issue . i have added on each API call the auth filter to the jersey client instead of one time on the client creation ...so on the error i got endless stack ...thanks for the support anyway guys.